# xpath expression with attribute in Element tree python

Tags: python, elementtree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree: ET = ET.parse(file)
tree.find('.//ns1:tag/@someattribute', ns)
```

is resulting in **{KeyError}'@'**, xpath expression is correct as per my knowledge, is there any way in element tree to get attribute value directly using xpath and not using **.attrib**

Comment: @MartinHonnen May I ask why you put the xpath in string() ?

Comment: Hm, I see, interesting, I never knew about that string() functionality. Thanks for explaining! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath expression is syntactically OK. The problem is that `find()` locates only elements. It cannot be used to find attributes.

This should work:

```
attr = tree.find('.//ns1:tag', ns).get('someattribute')
```

---

With [lxml](http://lxml.de), you could use the `xpath()` method (which returns a list):

```
attr = tree.xpath('.//ns1:tag/@someattribute', namespaces=ns)[0]
```

Comment: Is there anyway in ET that can fetch even attributes using xpath

Comment: No there isn't, unfortunately. `@` is understood in predicates only (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).